# python os.system use 2 quotes in bash command

Tags: python, bash, os.system

I am creating a simple script that simplifies an SMS bash command.

in bash the command looks like this:

```
curl http://textbelt.com/text -d number=0000000000 -d "Message=Test01"
```

The problem is, when I put that into python it looks like this:

```
import os
os.system('curl http://textbelt.com/text -d number=9803554314 -d "Message=Test01"')
```

I get the error:

```
"success": false,

"message": "Number and message parameters are required."
```

How do is use double quotes?

Comment: I get the same error in python and bash.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using curl instead of one of the many Python solutions for HTTP?

Comment: The quotation marks don't make a difference.  The problem is not in Python.  Try the bash command you gave in bash, with or without the quotation marks.  You get the same error.

Comment: why would you do something so blasphemous against python when there are urllib and so many other libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change Message to message (lower case) and it should work:

**Your example** fails:

> > > os.system('curl http://textbelt.com/text -d number=9803554314 -d "Message=Test01"')
> > >       {
> > >         "success": false,
> > >         "message": "Number and message parameters are required."
> > >       }0

**Changed M to m on "Message"** works:

> > > import os
> > >       os.system('curl http://textbelt.com/text -d number=9803554314 -d "message=Test01"')
> > >       {
> > >         "success": true
> > >       }0

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks man. I really overlooked that one, I was expecting to have to write some complex code or something!